# MacTex can't find a package even though TeXlive says it is installed

Tags: packages, mactex, mac

I installed mactex on yosemite via homebrew. I want to use [this](https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet) package. If I search for it in texlive it says that it is installed.

[image]

However, if I try to compile the [example](https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet/blob/master/example.tex) file by pressing the "Typeset" button I get get this error

```
Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'bayesnet'. 
I looked for files named tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex and pgflibrarybayesnet.co
de.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees..

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

What should I do to fix this problem? How to I see what path TexShop is using to search for the package?

Comment: If I ask for `brew info texlive`, I get the message `We recommend using a MacTeX distribution: https://www.tug.org/mactex/`

Comment: The bug has been solved with yesterday's (September 6, 2015) update, see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-September/037311.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Important information** As of September 7, 2015, the `tikz-bayesnet` package in TeX Live has been upddated, so the following answer is not relevant for whoever has revision 38295 in TeX Live.
>
> If `tlmgr tikz-bayesnet` gives
>
> ```
> package:     tikz-bayesnet
> category:    Package
> shortdesc:   Draw Bayesian networks, [...]
> installed:   Yes
> revision:    38295
> [...]
> ```
>
> or a larger revision number, the problem should not appear.

---

I suggest you to install MacTeX from the image you get at http://tug.org/mactex, rather than with Homebrew (which is what they recommend, too).

Your screen shot suggests you're using TeX Live Utility and indeed the response is good. Unfortunately, the packaging of `tikz-bayesnet` is wrong. If I do

```
tlmgr info tikz-bayesnet --list
```

from the terminal, the output is

```
package:     tikz-bayesnet
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Draw Bayesian networks, graphical models and directed factor graphs.
longdesc:    The package provides a library supporting the display of Bayesian networks, graphical models and (directed) factor graphs in LaTeX.
installed:   Yes
revision:    30094
sizes:       doc: 85k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 0.1
cat-date:    2014-02-26 23:03:13 +0100
cat-license: lppl1.3
collection:  collection-pictures
Included files, by type:
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/LICENSE_GPL
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/LICENSE_LPPL
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/README.rst
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/example.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/model_citation_influence.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/model_lda.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/model_pca.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/model_pca2.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex
```

One can check this also with TeX Live Utility, by right clicking on the package name in the main window (“Packages” tab), to get

[image]

Alas! The file `tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex` ends up in the `doc` subtree, instead of the `tex` one. The correct response should be

```
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-bayesnet/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex
```

It's a bug that should be made known in the TeX Live mailing list

http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live

Meanwhile, you can do

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/tikz-bayesnet
cp /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-bayesnet/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/tikz-bayesnet
```

remembering to remove the file when the bug is solved.

Instead of using the terminal you can also copy the file manually in the Finder, creating the folders under `~/Library/texmf` as shown.